# Is reading fields of a Realm object being slower than java objects?

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm thinking of using Realm.io as my ORM in production app.

As I understand from the docs RealmResults objects are stored in the BackendStore (disk) instead of on the RAM, as RealmResult is only a proxy of the real objects saved in the database.

So my question is, will reading the fields of a RealmObject being as quick as reading it from a normal Java object, given that Java objects are stored on RAM. I have many readings in my app, and I'm afraid this is going to affect responsiveness.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you're comparing with. The `RealmResults` is the result of a query, and Realm doesn't copy the objects - on the contrary to a traditional ORM. Realm will only fetch the object when needed while a typical ORM will copy the objects to memory. Copying the objects from SQLite to plain Java objects is bound by I/O performance.

Accessing a `RealmObject` might be slower than accessing a plain Java object. But a plain Java object isn't persistent. Realm offers an in-memory option, which is a more direct comparison with plain Java objects. In-memory Realms have the property as Plain objects: you loose the data when the app closes.

So if you are spending a lot of time copying objects from SQLite in order to have fast in-memory objects, it might end up being slower overall.

Comment: So to get this right, every time I use a getter in a RealmObject it actually goes to take it from the db? Isn't there a cache layer or something? Otherwise what's the point in being quick getting the query if you're being slow getting the real object?

Comment: Every Realm object is backed by the Realm file. Internally, Realm is memory mapping the Realm file to memory which actually speeds things up as you don't have to deserialise the object.